# How to support https in a local proxy server?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome, proxy

I've written a small proxy server running on `localhost:8000` which is supposed to replace some content on specific urls, while leaving the other urls intact.

What it currently does is to replace `Example Domain` with `Hello World!` on the `example.com` page. To build this I used the [`proxy-tamper`](https://github.com/tsyd/proxy-tamper) package.

The code looks like this (saved in `proxy-server.js`):

```
"use strict";

const proxy = require('proxy-tamper').start({port: 8000});

// block share-term.me
proxy.tamper(/share-term.me\/$/, 'This content is blocked!');

// Replace the content on example.com
proxy.tamper(/example.com\/$/, request => {
  delete request.headers['accept-encoding'];
  request.onResponse(response => {
    response.body = response.body.replace(/Example Domain/g, 'Hello World!');
    response.headers['server'] = 'proxy-tamper 1337';
    response.headers['content-length'] = response.body.length;
    response.complete();
  });
});
```

Then, to start the proxy server I use:

```
node proxy-server.js
```

And finally, start `google-chrome-stable`, by setting the `--proxy-server` option:

```
google-chrome-stable --proxy-server='http=http://localhost:8000;https=http://localhost:8000' http://domain.com
```

This works nicely for `http://example.com` but fails for `https://example.com`. In fact it doesn't support `https`.

When I open `http://example.com` I see the replaced content:

> [image]

But when I open `https://example.com` (or any `https` url), it fails, ending with `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`:

> [image]

How can I add `https` support for my proxy server, or at least make Chrome bypass the `https` urls to `http`?

I tried running the Chrome process using `--ignore-certificate-errors` and `--allow-insecure-content`, but they didn't help.

I'm not primary interested to have a strong https-related security, but I want to proxy these https requests through my server and send the responses on the client.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like proxy-tamper has no functionality for https requests. It only supports http (as of writing this and looking at the documentation).

You could use the package [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) instead. There's a nice section on supporting https [here](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#using-https).

**Edit** Can someone verify whether you can actually change https response bodies server side? Won't this information technically be encrypted? Isn't decryption on the server technically breaching the protocol and not allowed?

Comment: I tried `http-proxy`, but I was reading [here](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/issues/382) that there's no simple solution to modify the response content. Any ideas?

Comment: @IonicăBizău I'll need to check, let me get back to you. Server-side this should be possible but the package might not support modifications to the content without editing the package itself.

Comment: I'd be happy with modifying the package and then contributing, as long I have a minimal example of a proxy server with HTTPs support.

Comment: @IonicăBizău Oh, [transformer-proxy](https://github.com/philippotto/transformer-proxy) is a middleware for http-proxy. You should be able to use it on the https responses obtained from the `http-proxy` package. Try using them in conjunction with one another.

Comment: I saw that too! Can you please create a minimal example that will replace the content only on specific pages (matched by regex)? I struggled with this for 3 days.... Thanks!

Comment: @IonicăBizău I'll have to look into it when I get home, but essentially you want to: Configure http-proxy, then write a function with a promise to handle the change asynchronously to change the data from X url into whatever you want. [harmon](https://github.com/No9/harmon) might also be able to do this, it has a nice example of how to with `http-proxy` on the Github page.

Comment: I also saw harmon... But couldn't find anywhere a clean example... Thanks for your help. Will probably give you a bounty if you find a clean solution.